# python flask iframe and download

Tags: python, forms, iframe, flask, action

I have to perform two actions based on radio button selection, either download or view a document

```
<form method="post" action="{{ url_for('page_after_submit') }}">
    <p> Your resume </p>
    <div class="radio">
        <label> <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios1" value="option1" checked> Download document </label>
    </div>
    <div class="radio">
        <label> <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios2" value="option2"> View document </label>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

My page_after_submit has this code...

```
@app.route(local.URL_PREFIX + '/page_after_submit/', methods=['POST'])
def after_submit():
    if 'option1' == request.form['optionsRadios']:
        return/redirect ("download from this url")
    if 'option2' == request.form['optionsRadios']:
        return/redirect ("view in this iframe")
return (Url_for('go back to submit page if you are here')
```

I know my form can only have one action which is '/page_after_submit/', what code (HTML or Python in flask) I need to complete rest of my actions ??? I tried to put the iframe tags with complete download file address in the redirect for option2 but doesn't work. I also want this iframe to pop up not open a new browser window. Plus for the download, don't know what to do specially different operating system may have different path for download directory.

My goal is to not have any javascript as well, don't know if it's possible or not. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to craft a different response depending on how they want to see the data.

**Download File**

If they choose option 1, you need to set the headers and response to allow the browser to trigger a file download. [Here's how you can do something like that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23354314/python-flask-downloading-a-file-returns-0-bytes).

**View File in Iframe**

If they choose option 2, you need to return an HTML response which loads the file. This can be done in an Iframe if you'd like, but it's not necessary. [Here's one possible way to do that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11790031/set-iframe-src-response-from-flask), but many others exist.